# Add new column to table in linqtosql dbml - The selected class cannot be deleted

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I wish to add a new column to a table, usually I would add the column in SQL and then remove/add the table in the dbml to refresh its definition.

But if I try to delete the table I get

> The selected class cannot be deleted because it is used as the return
>   type for one or more     DataContext methods.

What is the best way to get around this to add a new column?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to remove/add the table in dbml to refresh its definition. Just right click on your existing entity on dbml designer -> "Add Property". 
(*You can also do it on designer generated code file by adding new property*)

Comment: Right, but if you have several changes to the table, this makes it very tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 3):

When you updated table definition and trying to update DBML and getting this error, 
Go in to yourproject.designer.vb, search  for the "Table Name" , find related stored procedure and delete it. Then add table to DBML. Then add the related stored procedure again. That should solve your issue. Hope it will help